# What is the difference between this two condition?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements

What is the difference between this two conditions?. I tried to use both conditions but different output.

```
if(!(data1 == true || data2 == true))
{
   // do something
}
```

And

```
if(data1 != true || data2 != true)
 {
   // do something
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**fist condition :**

```
if(!(data1 == true || data2 == true))
{
   // do something
}
```

It will false the evaluated result if the result is true and if the result is false then the result will be true.

If `data1 == true` is true it will not check data2 condition and make all condition false. so if `data1 == true` then whole condition is false. Same as data1. And if data1 or data2 is false (one is false) then the code will be executed.

**Second Condition**

```
if(data1 != true || data2 != true)
 {
   // do something
 }
```

It will do the reverse of the first condition. First it will check that if data1 is not equal to true, so if data1 is false then the code will be executed.

Comment: That's the reason why it still execute my condition.

Answer (score 1):

`!(data1 == true || data2 == true)` this condition is same as `data1 != true && data2 != true`
Using ! operator with == gives != and using ! operator with || will give &&.
Your 2nd condition `data1 != true || data2 != true` will be same as your 1 st condition If you replace || with && in 2nd condition

Comment: That's why it run smoothly and got different result.

Comment: yes Both are valid conditions. Such type of errors are called logical error

Answer (score 1):

```
!(data1 == true || data2 == true)
```

This is equivalent of (see also [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)):

```
(data1 != true && data2 != true)
```

Which is obviously different from

```
(data1 != true || data2 != true)
```